# Unable to execute Fortran77 program after successful compilation

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have a Fortran program and have command to compile it. It compiles but after that even I am unable to execute it. Any help or detailed explanation would be highly appreciated. A part of the program which I am facing problem with is mentioned below.

```
 READ 20, ITEXT
  OPEN(14, STATUS='UNKNOWN')
  OPEN(3, STATUS='UNKNOWN')                    ! DIPAK                      
  OPEN(9, STATUS='UNKNOWN',FILE=ITEXT)                     ! EFG   1                    
  OPEN(10,STATUS='UNKNOWN',FILE='/usr/local/bin/EBTABLE.DAT',FORM='UNFORMATTED')  ! DIPAK                      
  OPEN(11,STATUS='UNKNOWN',FILE='/usr/local/bin/TL03_99.DAT',  FORM='UNFORMATTED')  ! DIPAK                      
  OPEN(12,STATUS='UNKNOWN', FORM='UNFORMATTED',                               
 1ACCESS='DIRECT',RECL=8192)
  OPEN(13,STATUS='UNKNOWN', FORM='UNFORMATTED',                               
 1ACCESS='DIRECT',RECL=8192)
```

The files EBTABLE.DAT and TL03_99.DAT are copied at the mentioned locations.

The command used for compiling it is given as:

```
fort77 -a -f -g -h -w8 ../cascade.f -o cascade
```

After this how should I execute, suppose my input file is named cascade.inp

Comment: Are you getting any error message? Why do you think the error is coming from this part of the code?

Comment: No. But I am unable to figure out what to do next. How to run the executable file, it's not working as in normal cases.

Comment: Are you able to compile and execute a simple "hello world" fortran program in your environment?

Comment: In the directory where you compiled cascade.f, there should be a file called cascade, if there were no compile errors.  To execute that (in linux) type the command ./cascade

Comment: Yes my fortran compiler is working fine.
And I am unable to execute using this command. './cascade', though there are no compile errors and I am getting executable file named cascade.

Comment: Place some print statements into your program and see where it stops. Better even is to add a MCE (Minimal Compiling Example) in the question and not just a snippet as you have. It is unclear what 'READ 20, ITEXT' does (i.e what is on unit 20, what the data type of ITEXT is). Also statements like "OPEN(14, STATUS='UNKNOWN')" are a bit dubious as it tries to open a default (system / compiler dependent file).

Comment: I am also not clear about those so far.

Comment: You're unable to run the executable using './cascade'? What happens when you type that?

Comment: There is not enough information about these files. You need to provide more information on the types of files you are using. ACTION='READ' or STATUS='SCRATCH' would assist in documenting the way the files are to be used. Alco consider using IOSTAT= and report any errors.